# trouble generating permutations

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to generate permutations given an array of distinct integers in Java, can't figure out what's wrong with my solution.

I know there are hundreds of solutions online for this, but I'm trying to do it using a specific approach that makes sense to me (rather than trying to memorize someone else's algorithm).
My logic is, given {1, 2, 3, 4}, I should loop through and recursively print

```
1 + permute({2, 3, 4})
2 + permute({1, 3, 4})
3 + permute({1, 2, 4})
4 + permute({1, 2, 3})
```

So basically add the current element to result, and recursively call permute on the remaining elements. However I'm not getting the right results and I can't figure out why, I've been staring at the code for hours.

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        getPerm(nums.length, nums, tmp, result);
        return result;
    }

    private void getPerm(int n, int[] a, ArrayList<Integer> tmp, ArrayList<List<Integer>> result){

       // System.out.println("Calling on array " + Arrays.toString(a));
          //  System.out.println("tmp is " + tmp.toString());
          //  System.out.println("n is " + n);



        if(n == 0){
            ArrayList<Integer> toAdd = new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp);
            result.add(toAdd);
            tmp.clear();
           // tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            tmp.add(a[i]);
            int[] b = new int[n-1];
            int k = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while(k<b.length){
                if(a[i]==a[j]){j++;}
                else{b[k]=a[j]; k++; j++;}
            }

            getPerm(n-1, b, tmp, result);
        }
    }
}

For input = [1, 2, 3]
Expect [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[1,3,2],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
But output is [[1,2,3],[3,2],[2,1,3],[3,1],[3,1,2],[2,1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your algorithm for the input {1,2,3}:

- First you add 1 to tmp
- Then you call getPerm(2, [2, 3], [1], [])
- Then you add 2 to tmp
- Then you call geterm (1, [3], [1, 2], [])
- Then you add 3 to tmp
- Then you call getPerm(0, [], [1, 2, 3], [])
- Now you add the first permutation [1, 2, 3] to the result and **clear tmp**
- Therefore the next permutation which should be [1, 3, 2] will be lacking 1

This can be fixed if instead of clearing tmp each time you add a permutation to the result, you remove just the last element added to `tmp` after the recursive call:

```
private void getPerm(int n, int[] a, ArrayList<Integer> tmp, ArrayList<List<Integer>> result)
{
    if(n == 0){
        ArrayList<Integer> toAdd = new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp);
        result.add(toAdd);
        // don't clear tmp here
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        tmp.add(a[i]);
        int[] b = new int[n-1];
        int k = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while(k<b.length){
            if(a[i]==a[j]){j++;}
            else{b[k]=a[j]; k++; j++;}
        }

        getPerm(n-1, b, tmp, result);
        tmp.remove(tmp.size()-1); // remove the last element added to tmp
    }
}
```

Now the output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```